# Defining "this" within a JavaScript function and also sending the function an arguement

Tags: javascript

I have a function called myFunction().

Within myFunction, I want "this" to refer to the parent's "this".

Ok, I will call myFunction as `myFunction.call(this)`.

Great!

Oops, Now I need to pass an argument to myFunction.  Normally, I would just use `myFunction(myArg)`, but that call thing kind of messed me up.

How can this be done?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters following the first will be passed as individual arguments to your function [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
myFunction.call(this, argument_1, argument_2);
```

Alternatively you could use apply which allows you to pass the arguments as an array (or an array like object) [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
myFunction.apply(this, argsArray);
```

Comment: Thanks net.uk.sweet (and also Adidi!).  I've tried tried but it didn't work the first time.  Let me try again until it works!

Answer (score 2):

[Javascript Call Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

After the bind you can send the function all the arguments you want

```
myFunction.call(this,arg1,arg2,...);
```